# Concatenate URL and display the image in the URL PHP

Tags: php, json, url

my question is how do you concatenate para1 and para2, and displays the image that is in the url for each of the data in the web1 array in PHP?

Here is an example of what I wanted.

From url1: www.example.com/jferf0923i092eijodsojs

Please keep in mind that these urls are just an example of what I want to achieve.

```
{"Web 1": {
      "url1": {
        "para1": "www.example.com",
        "para2": /jferf0923i092eijodsojs,
      },
      "url2": { 
        "para1": "www.example.com",
        "para2": asjdoisadj829332oijd,
      },
      "url3": {
        "para1": "www.example.com",
        "para2": assasdijoj21389445,
      }
      }}
```

I appreciate your help! Cheers

Comment: Well, you simply decode that JSON string, concatenate the elements to your liking and output and then use the result the way you want. What is your question here? Please do not answer: "I want  someone else to do my work for me"...

Comment: relax dude, I am asking you kindly, I am really new with PHP, I can't show the image, I can only show the url. Thats why I am asking. FYI, not everyone has mastered PHP like you (I'm assuming you are).

Comment: I am quite relaxed, don't worry. However this site expects two things of those asking questions: 1. to have a minimal understanding of the tools they use and 2. to have invested effort themselves into solving their issue and posting the results of that effort. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ya dude seriously, maybe people like you whos making this site so unfriendly for people whos learning. Congrats on mastering PHP by yourself.

Comment: I am sorry that I offend you. Actually that was not my motivation. I would like to suggest that _you_ take a deep breath and first _think_ about what I wrote. Why don't you simply do as I ask and post your code here along with an explanation what exactly it is you fail to get working? That way we all would be happy to help. But just dumping some vague description and expecting others to do your work for you is simply considered off-topic here. And there are _very_ good reasons for that, reasons that make this place as successful as it is. So stop rumbling, post your code.

Comment: To be honest I know how to concatenate and stuff, however I have no idea how to make it as an html image since I am making a PHP. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is roughly what you are looking for, at least it should give you a start:

```
<?php
$catalog = [
    "Web 1" => [
        "url1" => [
            "para1" => "www.example.com",
            "para2" => "jferf0923i092eijodsojs",
        ],
        "url2" => [
            "para1" => "www.example.com",
            "para2" => "asjdoisadj829332oijd",
        ],
        "url3" => [
            "para1" => "www.example.com",
            "para2" => "assasdijoj21389445",
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($catalog as $entry) {
    foreach ($entry as $url) {
        $imageUrl = sprintf('https://%s/%s', $url['para1'], $url['para2']);
        echo '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '">'."\n";
    }
}
```

The output is valid html and should visualize the image when used inside an html page:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/jferf0923i092eijodsojs">
<img src="https://www.example.com/asjdoisadj829332oijd">
<img src="https://www.example.com/assasdijoj21389445">
```

Comment: Hey man, appreciate your help.